# How to reconcile forecasts when multiple hierarchies are present, in R using hts package?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have multiple timeseries with **total series** dis-aggregated in multiple hierarchies.  Two such hierarchies are shown below:

[image: First Hierarchy] [image: Second hierarchy]

These are hierarchies and not group.

How can I use the hts package to make reconciled forecasts?

Comment: See Example 2 here: http://pkg.earo.me/hts/reference/gts-class.html

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I did look at it. The problem I have is that I have 182 base time series. Different hierarchies in themselves have different levels and they use only few of these base hierarchies. The top level is the same for each hierarchy.